# Do you need license for publishing android apps?

Tags: android

Do you need license for publishing android apps? (Not on play store but the direct download way)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mostly related to Android.SE site.

Comment: off-topic but, simple No. You dnt need a license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a license for publishing apps in the Google play store. However for bug testing your application in your phone or a friends phone or an emulator you do not need a license. That is, not a paid license. An auto (I believe it to be auto) generated free license is generated to install your app on the device

I Hope This Helps.